# Flanging effect in Digital Audio

Tags: signal-processing, adc, feed-forward, audioeffect, digital-filter

If I have a sine wave of following properties

```
amplitude = 0.8
Sample Rate= 44100
Frequency = 440 Hz
Time = 2 sec
```

which can be written as

```
x(t) = 0.8*sin(2*Pi*440*t/(44100*2)) //where t is the 't'th sample in 44100*2 samples.
```

How can we produce Flanging Effect over this sine wave?
Can we add a phase shifted wave of the same wave to produce the effect?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia: Flanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanging), you do just that (to get the purest version of a flanger): add a shifted version, i.e.

```
y(t) = x(t) + x(t - N)
```

where `N` would be chosen to be less or equal to a 20 ms shift, so up to 882 samples for a sampling frequency of 44.1 kHz.